# AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() always returns null in Kotlin

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin

I am using Facebook Sdk in kotlin. When I try to use FB share listener `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` returns null. I tried  `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this)` but it already deprecated. How can I solve this problem

```
 fun SetFacebookShareListener(sd: ShareDialog) {

            sd.registerCallback(mCallbackManagerFacebook, object : FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> {
                override fun onSuccess(result: Sharer.Result) {
                    // Toast.makeText(DetailsFragment.this.getActivity(), "You shared this post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    val builder1 = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                    val activeSession = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
                    if (activeSession == null) {
                        builder1.setMessage("Do you want us to Connect to your account with facebook?")
                    } else if (!activeSession.permissions.contains("publish_actions")) {
                        builder1.setMessage("Do you want us to automatically post your reward details at your facebook timeline?")
                    }

                    builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, which ->
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        this@MainActivity.ConnectWithFacebook()
                    }

                    builder1.setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, which ->
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    val alert = builder1.create()
                    alert.show()
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "test2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                override fun onError(e: FacebookException) {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            })
        }
```

and Connect with facebook is

```
 fun ConnectWithFacebook() {


    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"))

}
```

Comment: To help with troubleshooting, what happens when you try `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this)` in your application's `onCreate()` method? This could potentially be due to the Facebook SDK not properly initializing upon application start.

Comment: FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this) deprecated in new sdk. any way I am also try this. but no luck for me.

Comment: Is this happening after a successful Facebook login? Would you mind posting your code for `ConnectWithFacebook()`?

Comment: Facebook login will done on the first time the app launch. this is after login . This functionality  working inside the app